# Red Black tree with pagination

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

As most people know the Set Container in C++ is usually implemented as a red-black tree, and when iterating over the container the entries come out in order, and this can be exploited.

I would however like to do pagenation on the iteration of the container, forinstance if the container containes :

```
set<int> set;
// insert some data
for(auto s : set)
    cout << s << " " << endl;

1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15
```

I would like to du a range query on the container `range(2,5)` yealding: the vector `3, 5, 7`, this seem imposible to do with the set, is it possible to do pagination on any of the STL containers, or is this a case of you have to implement it your self?

Comment: Ok, now that i understand your question (I think), would [`std:next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and/or [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) based from `std::begin(s)` provide you with what you're looking for ? I *think* it may.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a way to do this taking less than linear time in the standard library, but it's not difficult to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For indexing there is only one way http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/
But it has linear time complexity

```
set<int>::iterator lower = s.begin();
std::advance(lower, 2);
auto upper = lower;
std::advance(upper, 6-2);
std::copy(lower, upper, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Yeah, I went there. he's look for ranging via index-position; not element-value.

Comment: this is however still linear in the advance argument, this should be doable in log time, but might demand information that is not kept in the underlying rb_tree.